# MySQL JOIN with SUBQUERY very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a forum and I would like to see the latest topics with the author's name and the last user who answered

Table Topic (forum)

```
| idTopic | IdParent | User | Title | Text             |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 0        | Max  | Help! | i need somebody  | 
--------------------------------------------------------
| 2       | 1        | Leo  |       | What?!           |
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Question.*,
    Response.User AS LastResponseUser 
FROM Topic AS Question
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT User, IdParent  
   FROM Topic 
   ORDER BY idTopic DESC
) AS Response 
    ON ( Response.IdParent = Question.idTopic )
WHERE Question.IdParent = 0
GROUP BY Question.idTopic
ORDER BY Question.idTopic DESC
```

Output:

```
| idTopic | IdParent | User | Title | Text             | LastResponseUser |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 0        | Max  | Help! | i need somebody  | Leo              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22f72/4

The query works, but is very slow (more or less 0.90 seconds over 25'000 record).

How can I make it faster?

**UPDATE**

comparison between the proposed solutions

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94068/22

Comment: Do you have an index on `Question.idTopic`?

Comment: Show the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: @Barmar yes! primary key for idTopic and index on idParent

Comment: Why the fsck would you make a subquery that selects from one table only, with no aggrataion and not even any filtering? That doesn't make sense!

Comment: Will you only ever have one level of responses (i.e. each question can have a number of responses, but a response can't also be a question)?  That's implied by your select statement (i.e. it's non-recursive).  If so, I'd split questions and responses into separate tables; that way you'll reduce the amount of data you need to query over.

Comment: You don't need the order by in the subquery...  Ordering is expensive

Comment: @xQbert I need to get the latest response

Comment: But you're not getting the latest response. You're getting all the responses, ordered by `idTopic`.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I'm not developing, but I would like to optimize an existing one. I would like to avoid big changes

Comment: @Barmar idTopic is Auto-incremental

Comment: It doesn't matter. You're not limiting the number of rows you're returning in the subquery.

Comment: See this question for how to get the latest row in a group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: To return something latest, the query should use some aggregation (that is contain the GROUP BY clause).

Comment: @Barmar right, the problem is definitely the large number of records in the subquery .. but I do not know how I can fix it...

Comment: I gave you a link to a question that shows how to do it.

Comment: @newtover you're right, I fixed the example

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the link! I will try all the different solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using your current schema, I'd recommend adding indexes (particularly a clustered index (primary key)) and simplifying your SQL to let mySQL do the work of optimising the statement, rather than forcing it to run a subquery, sort the results, then run the main query.

```
CREATE TABLE Topic (
  idTopic  INT
  ,IdParent INT
  ,User     VARCHAR(100)
  ,Title    VARCHAR(255)
  ,Text     VARCHAR(255)       
  ,CONSTRAINT Topic_PK PRIMARY KEY (idTopic) 
  ,CONSTRAINT Topic_idTopic_UK UNIQUE (idTopic) 
  ,INDEX Topic_idParentIdTopic_IX (idParent, idTopic)
);


INSERT INTO Topic (idTopic, IdParent, User, Title, Text) VALUES 
(1, 0, 'Max', 'Help!', 'i need somebody'),
(2, 1, 'Leo', '', 'What!?');


SELECT Question.*
, Response.User AS LastResponseUser 
FROM Topic AS Question
LEFT JOIN Topic AS Response 
  ON Response.IdParent = Question.idTopic
WHERE Question.IdParent = 0
order by Question.idTopic
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f1bc/1

**Update**

In the comments you mentioned you only want the most recent response.  For that, try this:

```
SELECT Question.*
, Response.User AS LastResponseUser 
FROM Topic AS Question
LEFT JOIN (
  select a.user, a.idParent 
  from Topic as a
  left join Topic as b
  on b.idParent = a.idParent
  and b.idTopic > a.idTopic
  where b.idTopic is null 
) AS Response 
  ON Response.IdParent = Question.idTopic
WHERE Question.IdParent = 0
order by Question.idTopic
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f1bc/3

Comment: I apologize if my question was unclear. I think your answer does not work with more than one answer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39d6/1

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, your answer works on sqlfiddle. Tomorrow I'll try on production db.

Comment: Among all the solutions, this was the fastest

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the highest IDTopic is the last responses user...
and assuming you want to return topics without responses...

```
Select A.IDTopic, A.IDParent, A.User, A.Title, A.Text, 
case when b.User is null then 'No Response' else B.User end as LastReponseUser
FROM topic A
LEFT JOIN Topic B
 on A.IdTopic = B.IDParent
 and B.IDTopic = (Select max(IDTopic) from Topic 
                  where IDParent=B.IDParent group by IDParent)
WHERE  A.IDParent =0
```

Comment: Updated to correct issue wtih missing then and limit results to only include parent topics.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, your answer works on sqlfiddle. Tomorrow I'll try on production db.